# Permission denied when trying any dotnet EF command

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC web app. I implemented the models and I'm trying to add migrations or using any EF dotnet commands - but this is what I get:

```
MacBook-Pro:E_sign jennansowayan$ dotnet ef migrations add
```

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): Permission denied
>
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Exe.Run(String executable, IReadOnlyList`1 args, String workingDirectory, Boolean interceptOutput)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Project.FromFile(String file, String buildExtensionsDir, String framework, String configuration, String runtime)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute(String[] _)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(String[] args)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4303